# Unity tray panel shows icon as split into two

Tags: unity

I am running default Ubuntu Unity, never changed any theme. And this has happened by itself, first for a single icon, then for all.

[image]

I tried rebooting thinking the ATI drivers might have gone nuts and reloading everything should work fine but it didn't.

One thing to add is that when I open up any dropdown, that menu icon is shown fine as long as the dropdown is open.

Comment: This is really a Bug. If you want to help the developers fix it, please take the time to [file a bug report for it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @Stefano It may be a bug but I don't understand why this question was closed? Someone can atleast tell me some means to fix it for me & I believe that's not something off for what Stackexchange network is.

Comment: Right, we don't believe that bug reports fit the question-answer format and scope of the site, as outlined in the faq. If you file a bug report, people will usually discuss workarounds to get rid of the problem until the bug is fixed, that's what the Launchpad bug-tracker is for. It's much more helpful to the community, if the relevant developers know about the problem.

Comment: Ok! I reported the bug. Its here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/805680